# Comparing probability of values existing in different csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to:

i.) create a list containing all csv files in a given folder- I have done this

ii.) create a for loop to iterate through each file name and read it as a pandas dataframe - done

iii.) look for the probability of the anonymous id in the first file appearing in the second file (1 if exists, 0 if not). I think I have built this logic into my for loop

iv.) return a dataframe for each of the comparisons showing the anonymous_id and 1's and 0's depending on whether or not the anonymous id was found (i have built this logic into my loop to the best of my ability)

v.) I then want to convert each of the dataframes into separate csv's with names based on the two files being compared (I have done this too).

This is the code I have written:

```
files = ['Session.csv','lead.csv','opportunity.csv','lead.csv']
for i in range(1,len(files)):
    file_path = '/Users/emmanuels/Documents/'
    first = pd.read_csv(file_path+files[i-1])
    second = pd.read_csv(file_path+files[i])
    first['probability'] = first.anonymous_id.isin(second.anonymous_id).astype(int)
    first.to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/'+str(first[:-4]+'to'+second[:-4]+'.csv'))
```

This however returns this error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching
>   types dtype('

here is a sample of pertinent columns in three of the files:

session.csv

```
<bound method Series.to_dict of 0    0000c924-5959-4e2d-8757-0d10f96ca462
1    00044853-26bc-4c38-93a7-cad6860640ac
2    00074e2d-f7aa-4fd1-baaa-06e56961d15a
3    000f3947-1255-457f-b9bf-81cea6a62075
4    000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6
5    000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6
6    000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6
7    000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6
8    000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6
9    000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6
Name: anonymous_id, dtype: object>
```

lead.csv:

```
<bound method Series.to_dict of 0    0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
1    0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
2    0000f8ea-3aa6-4423-9247-1d9580d378e1
3    0014f7ea-c02b-4452-86ac-a0aa839f226e
4    000ab05c-d136-429a-b461-de420d917cdf
5    0006b984-fbf7-44eb-bdb3-bf3d1bf5dbf9
6    00145627-7cf8-4bc9-9529-38810164f254
7    00145627-7cf8-4bc9-9529-38810164f254
8    00041416-6178-4726-b31f-18289bcee55c
9    00041416-6178-4726-b31f-18289bcee55c
Name: anonymous_id, dtype: object>
```

opportunity.csv:

```
<bound method Series.to_dict of 0    0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
1    0002269a-1e39-4cdf-a43e-cecf0a277c1c
2    000efd5a-8ec6-4a3a-904d-7376b651da26
3    00031151-9521-4895-a593-eb06033ea6f7
4    00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a
5    00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a
6    00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a
7    00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a
8    00074004-adc1-4142-9526-538eb3d71eee
9    0007af07-4bfa-4b09-93df-a1702f496e59
Name: anonymous_id, dtype: object>
```

Comment: I guess `str(first[:-4]+'to'+second[:-4]+'.csv')` won't work since `first` and `second` are dataframes - however, you want strings (the file names) right?

Comment: try `first.to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/'+str(files[i-1][:-4]+'to'+files[i][:-4]+'.csv'))` instead